What is the reletive permeability of structual steel?
Help, i need to know what the reletive permeability is of a few materials (listed below) but i can not find the data on the internet. Does annybody know the data or where i can find it?
-s235jr
-s355jr
-s690ql
-hardox 450
-abramax 420 cr
I hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Rarely is the permeability of a structural steel relevant to much of anything. If you need to screen magnetic fields use mu-metal instead.

It is for a electromagnet, and to make the whole magnet from mu-metal would be quite expensive and difficult to make.

ROger that. Mu metal would be a disaster then. IT would seem you would drive the structure to saturation fairly easily for a large electromagnet.

That is true, but i will be using alluminium windings because of the weight, and a large length of the core makes the saturation the magnetic flux density less.
